# Adding additional dns search domains - is there a maximum?

Tags: networking, dns

I've just moved to Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, I have added a bunch of search domains to the network settings (using Settings -> Network -> Wired -> Options... -> IPv4 Settings).

It seems to have picked up some of the domains I have added, but not all. I use quite a few domains at work so being able to add them all would be really useful. Is there a way to do this? /etc/resolv.conf seems to have 6 of the 10 domains that I had added so I'm assuming that 6 is the limit?

Thanks
Guy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **6 domains with a maximum total of 256 characters** is the maximum amount of search domains.

This is a limitation by the BIND DNS client library in GNU libc and is not easily changed.

See this [great answer on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245888/271588) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that's a shame. Ok well I guess I can create a bunch of aliases for connections that I use frequently

Comment: yes, I know....